# Error when clicking on a material textfield dropdown list in Android

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, material-components-android

I have the following material textfield in my `create_pool_details_layout` xml view:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/numPlayersDropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:hint="Number of Player to Purchase"
        android:labelFor="@+id/numOfPlayersSelected" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/numOfPlayersSelected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and the following item for the autocompletetextview in my `number_of_players_dropdown_layout` xml view:

```
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" />
```

In my Activity class I have the following:

```
public class CreatePoolDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    // BILLING PROCESSOR
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    //
    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Activity activity = null;

    private EditText inputPoolName, inputPoolPassword, inputConfirmPoolPassword, inputPoolNote;
    private Button btnCreatePool, btnCancel;

    //
    private static FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private DatabaseReference iapReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("IAP");

    private SkuDetails playerQtySKU;

    private AutoCompleteTextView numPlayersSelected;

    ArrayList<String> numPlayersArray;
    
    ArrayAdapter<String> numPlayersAdapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    

        setContentView(R.layout.create_pool_details_layout);

        // Set the activity to 'this'
        activity = this;


        iapReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    int counter = 0;

                    skuList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot pickSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        counter = counter + 1;

                        String sku = pickSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                        skuList.add(sku.toLowerCase());

                        if (counter == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {

                            connectToGooglePlayBilling();

                         }
                     
                     }
                 
                 }
                 
             }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
     
         });


         inputPoolName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.poolname);

         inputPoolPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.poolpassword);

         inputConfirmPoolPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);

         inputPoolNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.poolNote);

         btnCreatePool = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_pool_button);

         btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);


         billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull @NotNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable List<Purchase> list) {

                }

            })
            .build();

     }
 
}


private void connectToGooglePlayBilling() {

    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                getProductDetails();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Finally:

```
private void getProductDetails() {


    SkuDetailsParams getProductDetailsQuery = SkuDetailsParams
            .newBuilder()
            .setSkusList(skuList)
            .setType(INAPP)
            .build();

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(getProductDetailsQuery, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull @NotNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null) {

                numPlayersSelected = findViewById(R.id.numOfPlayersSelected);
                //
                numPlayersArray = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    numPlayersArray.add(list.get(i).getTitle());

                }


                // THE ERROR SEEMS TO OCCUR HERE!!!
                numPlayersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.number_of_players_dropdown_layout, numPlayersArray);

                numPlayersSelected.setAdapter(numPlayersAdapter);

                numPlayersSelected.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        playerQtySKU = list.get(i);

                    }

                });

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Which throws the following error, which i do not understand why its happening!?

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Filter.convertResultToString(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.convertSelectionToString(AutoCompleteTextView.java:927)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildImeCompletions(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1246)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1203)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java:151)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.showHideDropdown(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:332)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.access$500(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:71)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate$9.onTouch(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:459)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12537)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:399)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12789)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5291)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4651)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4617)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4625)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4814)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4651)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4617)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4625)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7354)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7323)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7274)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEve
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.replaysport.pickemparty, PID: 13894
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Filter.convertResultToString(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.convertSelectionToString(AutoCompleteTextView.java:927)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildImeCompletions(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1246)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1203)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java:151)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.showHideDropdown(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:332)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.access$500(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:71)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate$9.onTouch(DropdownMenuEndIconDelegate.java:459)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12537)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:399)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12789)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5291)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4651)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4617)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4625)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4814)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4651)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4617)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4625)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7354)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7323)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7274)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7471)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)`
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that stack trace came from that exact code? Is `ArrayAdapter` the platform class, or is it your own custom class?

Comment: @MikeM. platform class, i did not implement any customization

Comment: Hmm, dunno. The only way I can figure that particular Exception happening is if the `AutoCompleteTextView`'s `Adapter` gives a null `Filter`, but `ArrayAdapter` won't do that.

Comment: @MikeM. well the error sates `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Filter.convertResultToString(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference` which its referencing a Filter!? Im so confused...

Comment: `AutoCompleteTextView` does some prep work right before showing its dropdown, including using the `Filter` to get the current item texts. That `Filter` comes from the `Adapter` set on the `AutoCompleteTextView`. As you can see in [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#522), `ArrayAdapter` can't really return a null `Filter`. About the only thing that could cause the given stack trace is if the `Adapter` returns a null `Filter`, so my first thought is that either the code or the stack trace here isn't current.

Comment: @MikeM. I have edited my question to include the full code, which what I provided earlier was also current (including the stack trace). Let me know if you see anything that sticks out to you.

Comment: @MikeM. sorry about that, i do assign it on the onCreate function `activity = this;`, i updated my question to reflect that as well. Again sorry for not adding that in initially

Comment: @MikeM. i am thinking that the issue has to be there since if i comment that line out `numPlayersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, …);`, the view shows up fine and if i click on the material textview item the app doesn't crash, but nothing is displayed as well...

Comment: Yeah, `AutoCompleteTextView` works just fine with a null `Adapter`. It's only when you have an `Adapter` that specifically returns null from `getFilter()` that would cause the given Exception, AFAICT.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind atm is that maybe there's some sort of race condition with the Firebase callbacks, but that doesn't really make sense to me either. What happens if you set up the `AutoCompleteTextView` with dummy data directly in `onCreate()` instead?

Comment: @MikeM. so what/how can the adapter return null from getFilter!?

Comment: @MikeM. even if i use a static `String []` like such `String[] type = new String[] {"item1", "item2", "item3"};` and try and use it `numPlayersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.number_of_players_dropdown_layout, type);` i get the exact same error!?

Comment: Threading mishap would be the only way that I can see, with `ArrayAdapter`, but everything you've shown should be running on the UI thread, methinks.

Comment: @MikeM. still in the call back, should i move it to onCreate u think?

Comment: At least for testing right now, yeah.

Comment: @MikeM. so if i move all the code to the onCreate it works just fine...

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for assisting on finding the reason it was crashing, now i just dont understand why its crashing. I "think" it should work as I had coded it in the callback, but im new to android app dev so i'm likely wrong. Also thx you for offering to go to a discussion room, i had to step away and was not able to accept it on time.

Comment: I don't know. I just cannot reproduce the given Exception with the described behavior. There must be something else going on in the overall setup. In any case, if it's working in `onCreate()`, you can leave it there and only update the list in the callback; e.g., https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTlS3YKAts2s9wvbaUzOXkZFuZjXqPuZ/view?usp=sharing. I have no idea if the underlying issue will cause problems with this setup too, though.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally deleted the chat room comment. My bad. We can still use it though: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246914/discussion-between-mike-m-and-learn2code.

Comment: @MikeM. it works as you have in your example!!! Put that as the answer and you are getting the CHECKMARK!!!! THX U again for all the time you spent helping me resolve this!!!!!

Comment: Ah, cool. No problem! If I ever figure out what was happening there, I'll let you know, but doing whatever setup you can in `onCreate()` is usually preferred anyway. I don't post answers here anymore, so please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad we got something working. Cheers!